# Matching BigQuery data with Traffic Acquisition GA4 report

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I'm new to BigQuery and I'm trying to replicate the Traffic Acquisition GA4 report, but not very successfully at the moment, as my results are not even remotely close to the GA4 view.

1. I understand that the source/medium/campaign fields are event-based and not session-based in GA4 / BQ. My question is, why not every event has a source/medium/campaign as an event_parameter_key? It seems logical for me to have these parameters for the 'session_start' event, but unfortunately, it's not the case
2. I tried the following options to replicate the Traffic Acquisition report:

2.1 To check the first medium for sessions:

```
with cte as ( select
    PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", event_date) AS Date,
    user_pseudo_id,
    concat(user_pseudo_id,(select value.int_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'ga_session_id')) as session_id,
    FIRST_VALUE((select value.string_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'medium')) OVER (PARTITION BY concat(user_pseudo_id,(select value.int_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'ga_session_id')) ORDER BY event_timestamp) as first_medium

FROM `project`)

select Date, first_medium, count(distinct user_pseudo_id) as Users, count (distinct session_id) as Sessions
from cte
group by 1,2;
```

The query returns 44k users with 'null' medium and 1.8k organic users while there are 17k users with the 'none' medium and 8k organic users in GA4.

2.2 If I change the first medium to the last medium:

```
FIRST_VALUE((select value.string_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'medium')) OVER (PARTITION BY concat(user_pseudo_id,(select value.int_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'ga_session_id')) ORDER BY event_timestamp desc) as last_medium
```

Organic medium increases to 9k users, though the results are still not matching the GA4 data.

2.3 I've also tried this code - https://www.ga4bigquery.com/traffic-source-dimensions-metrics-ga4/ - *source / medium (based on session)*, and still got completely different results compared to the GA4.

Any help would be much appreciated!

**UPDATE:**
I found this article which is very detailed and greatly explains how to query traffic sources data. It's the best one I've found so far:

[Query the GA4 Session Last Non-direct Traffic Source in BigQuery](https://tanelytics.com/ga4-bigquery-session-traffic_source/)

Answer (score 2):

I have noticed the samething, looking deeper I pulled 1 days worth of data from big query into google sheets and examined it.

Unsurprisingly I could replicate the results from ga4bigquery codes you have mentioned above results but they did not align with GA4 and although close for high traffic pages could be wildly out for the lower ones.

I then did a count for  'email' in event parmas source & ea_tracking_id as well as traffic_source and found they are all lower than the GA4 analytics.

I went to my dev site where I know exactly how many sessions have a source of email GA4 analytics agreed but big query did not, Google seems to be allocating a some traffic to not set randomly.

I have concluded the problem is not in the SQL and not in the tagging but in the bigquery GA4 data source. I have logged a query with google and we will see what happens. Sorry its not a solution

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well. I had so much organic data, but no cpc data. This is what I did in bigquery:

For me personally I was running into google bigquery attributing my google / cpc sessions to google / organic. While I still don't know why that's the case, I found in event_parameters there is a key call 'gclsrc' which is populates the value.string_value with 'aw.ds' if the session came through google ads (aka google / cpc).

I checked my data and sure enough a certain percentage of sessions had the gclsrc = aw.ds key to value.string_value even if it was google / organic traffic.

I extracted the parameter like so: max(case when params.key = 'gclsrc' then params.value.string_value else null end) as session_gclsrc

then used it to convert those google / organic sessions that are really google / cpc in an if-statement.

Not sure if this is applicable, but I hope it helps!

Comment: That's interesting, thank you! Same for me, cpc traffic in BigQuery is significantly lower than in GA4 and sessions with the gclid parameter are attributed to google / organic